# iOS : Manage Localized Images

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have 2 sets of localized images for iPhone App. How should I place the images ? And how can I load into the app?

The folder structure is as follow:

```
For English version:
/MyApp/en.lproj/Localizable.strings , InfoPList.strings
/MyApp/en.lproj/*.png (images)

For Traditional Chinese version:
/MyApp/zh-Hant.lproj/Localizable.strings , InfoPList.strings
/MyApp/Resources/*.png (images)

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *locale = [[defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:locale ofType:@"lproj"];
NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
SomeViewController *vc = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:languageBundle];
```

I would like to use the same filename for both set of images and make it autoload. Is it possible?

Now I encounter a problem. In the debug console, it said:

```
NSBundle </Users/SomeUser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/1DC22505-1E78-4B5E-A794-DBF72DC786AE/MyApp.app/zh-Hant.lproj> (not yet loaded)
```

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you get the language bundle yourself? You could just localize the image file name like so:

```
NSString *imageName = NSLocalizedString(@"myimage_jp", @"localized image");
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

And in the `Localizable.strings` file just map that image name like so (assuming that japanese is your default language):

```
@"myimage_jp" = @"myimage_cn"
```

Of course you would have to have 2 versions of the image in the resources (`myimage_jp` and `myimage_cn`)

Comment: Where should I put the images ? Same folder ( All in `/MyApp/Resources/` or in their `.lproj` ) ?

Comment: If I set bundle to `nil` in initialization of view controller, the images are doing fine after restarting the app. Is there any method that can change the app images without restarting?

Comment: if I set bundle to the path of `en.lproj` or `zh-Hant.lproj`, the images faile to load with the error stated in the question.

Comment: What's up with this bundle stuff? You don't need NSBundle to load localized image resources.

Comment: I want to refresh the images ( change images' language ) once the language is changed. How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Also, how about localizing Launch Images ?