# code to get localization for images in IOS?

Tags: localization

I have set of images to which I want to localize in any other language.
I know the same for text :
"Sign In" = "Sign In";

Can someone help me with the images?

Answer (score 0):

[iOS : Manage Localized Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390266/ios-manage-localized-images)
- declare it programmatically like mentioned in this URL

OR

You can localize your images individually by declaring it in inspector section (define there in which language you want to localize it).